# is it possible on a mac to quicky see the desktop along with the last active window?

Tags: ui, productivity

Many times, I feel the need to keep the current window open while having access to the desktop.

A good scenario to picture where this could be handy is this:

Say, you are on a web page and you want to drag a picture to desktop. If you are seeing a piece of the desktop at that moment, then no problems, just drag the pic to that spot but, many times, it turns out that the entire desktop is covered by underlying other windows. Sure, there is a hot-corner trick you can apply that will get you the desktop, but that action will also take down the current window, the one you wanted to drag the picture from.

As far as I know, there is no way around this problem. 
So I end up minimizing the underlying windows to get a piece of the desktop to drag picture onto.

But I'll ask it anyway... 
Is there a way that would do what I'd like to do?

Comment: But You can use Hot Corner while you are dragging the picture to get to the Desktop right? Why do you need your window still opened? You can also hit `^ CTRL`+`↓ DOWN ARROW` to show the Desktop while dragging the picture.

Comment: Fantastic! Please post this as answer as opposed to comment so I can select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Hot Corner while you are dragging the picture to get to the Desktop.

You can also hit <kbd>^ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>↓ DOWN ARROW</kbd> to show the Desktop while dragging the picture.

You can also perform fingers spread gesture on the trackpad while dragging the picture, but it's a little tricky to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is in the Dock -

Hold  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  & Right Click > Hide Others

[image]

Alternatively & probably better than my original answer [I don't know if this is system-wide, but it does appear in all the apps I checked, Apple & 3rd party]
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>H</kbd>  is the key command to Hide Others

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clever. It answers my question. But, I'd go with Mateusz's solution. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Tetsujin, is there a way to assign this as a keyboard combination? - that would be awesome if we could prevent the additional steps of moving the mouse over the dock, then right click and then hide others. Any way to  teach mac that we can assign say, something like "option+esc" would effectively do the same?

Comment: Actually, there's a simpler way altogether, but I don't know if it's system-wide. Certainly works for most apps - Cmd/Opt/h is often Hide Others, usually in the [app name] menu. Will add to answer.

Comment: cmd/opt/h does work for me too. for the dragging  picture example, the hot corner trick works best. But in all other cases, your solution will work as a perfect alternative. Thanks a lot.